# Determine the exact number of epochs if I don't have a validation loss

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, loss

This is the link to the [translation french-english](https://github.com/syedshahzadraza/Encoder-Decoder-Model-with-Attention/blob/master/machine_translation_french_english.ipynb) that I'm following to train my model.
I changed the dataset that has answers and questions, the sequence length is 30 token, with training set of 180k pairs of questions/answers and 40k for test.

My question is: how am I supposed to determine the exact number of epochs since I noticed the code doesn't use the validation set, so I can't compare the train loss and the validation loss?

PS: the loss kept dropping until 0.12 in epoch 54 but the earlier epochs gave better results than the last, even though the loss is lot smaller.

Thanks in advance

Comment: If you could share a little bit of code here (a minimum reproducible example of your problem), it would be much easier to understand the issue.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: You could take some of your test set or training set and use as validation data before training.